# How do I get the time in miliseconds on windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I want to name my file after the current time in miliseconds since 1970.

At the moment I just have a counter and increment it after every new file. But when the app restarts the counter goes back to zero and I overwrite the files when I start saving them again.

So I was thinking if I just use the time in seconds or miliseconds then I wont have this problem.

So my question is how to I get the time in miliseconds on windows mobile.

This is what I am currently doing to generate my file names.

```
string fileName = savedCounter + ".jpg";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx)

> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth
>   of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.

```
DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
long totalMiliSecond = (currentDate.Ticks - unixEpoch.Ticks) /10000;
Console.WriteLine(totalMiliSecond);
string fileName = string.Concat(totalMiliSecond,".jpg");
Console.WriteLine(fileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime.UtcNow` gives you the current Utc time

`new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc)` gives you 1970

So you could use:

```
var savedCounter = Math.Round((DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds);
```

---

Some alternative naming strategies include:

- Given that not many copies of your app were around in 1970, you could probably use a baseline date like `new DateTime(2012,1,1,0,0,0)`
- You could also use a DateTime.ToString format like `yyyyMMddhhmmss` to achieve a string based on a date - and this might be easier for a human to read (e.g. using the debugger or the isolated storage explorer)

---

Aside - for performance reasons be aware that you shouldn't create too many files in one directory - http://appangles.com/blogs/mickn/wp7/how-many-files-are-too-many-files-for-windows-phone-7-isolated-storage-performance/ - at some point it makes sense to use a single file instead (e.g. a database)

Answer (score 2):

Are you just using the milliseconds to generate a unique filename? If so, you might be much better using Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use a timestamp to generate the name of the file, if multiple instances of your application can run concurrently, then there's still a chance of conflicts.  Regardless of whether or not you use a timestamp, you may want to do something like the following:

1. Initialize a counter to 0
2. Generate a name for the file, incorporating the counter into its name.
3. Try to create the file, opening it for exclusive R/W access and requiring that the file not already exist.
4. If the file creation failed for some reason, increment the counter and repeat steps 2-4.

In fact, this is most likely what routines like [`System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) do.

Answer (score 0):

Either use Time or even better with your current Architecture, save the current Counter into the IsolatedStorageSettings. Its easy to use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

it will be better to use Guid instead of DateTime.

```
string fileName = System.Guid.NewGuid() + ".jpg";
```